# How to convert an image (rgb/gray) inside a pdf to monochrom/bitonal one using itext and java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm writing a java programm to swap images inside a pdf. Due to the process of generation they are stored as high dpi, rgb images, but are bitonal/monochrome images. I'm using [itext](https://developers.itextpdf.com) 7.1.1, but also testet the latest dev version (7.1.2 snapshot).

I'm already able to extract the images from pdf and convert them to png or tif using indexed colours or gray (0 & 255 only) in imagemagick (also testet gimp).

I modified some code from [itext](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/image-examples/itext7-how-convert-colored-images-black-and-white), to replace the images inside the pdf, which does work for DeviceRGB- and DeviceGray-Images, but not for Bitonal ones:

```
public static Image readPng(String pImageFolder, int pImageNumber) throws IOException {
  String url = "./" + pImageFolder + "/" + pImageNumber + ".png";
  File ifile = new File(url);
  if (ifile.exists() && ifile.isFile()) {
    return new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(url));
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

public static void replaceStream(PdfStream orig, PdfStream stream) throws IOException {
  orig.clear();
  orig.setData(stream.getBytes());
  for (PdfName name : stream.keySet()) {
    orig.put(name, stream.get(name));
  }
}

public static void replaceImages(String pFilename, String pImagefolder, String pOutputFilename) throws IOException {
  PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pFilename), new PdfWriter(pOutputFilename));
  for (int i = 0; i < pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    PdfDictionary page = pdfDoc.getPage(i + 1).getPdfObject();
    PdfDictionary resources = page.getAsDictionary(PdfName.Resources);
    PdfDictionary xobjects = resources.getAsDictionary(PdfName.XObject);
    Iterator<PdfName> iter = xobjects.keySet().iterator();
    PdfName imgRef;
    PdfStream stream;
    Image img;
    int number;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      imgRef = iter.next();
      number = xobjects.get(imgRef).getIndirectReference().getObjNumber();
      stream = xobjects.getAsStream(imgRef);
      img = readPng(pImagefolder, number);
      if (img != null) {
        replaceStream(stream, img.getXObject().getPdfObject());
      }
    }
  }
  pdfDoc.close();
}
```

If i convert the images to tif and use them as replacement, there are dark images (all pixels are black) inside the pdf. If i try to use png-images, they are not shown and pdfimages complaints "Unknown compression method in flate stream".

Answer (score 0):

**FYI:** 
There was an error in my replaceStream: `getBytes()` deflates a PdfStream. All Stream-Attributes were copied, thus there was a Filter-Information saying FlateDecoding is necessary.

I had to tell `getBytes()`not to deflate by setting the decoded-Parameter to false: `getBytes(false)`

```
public static void replaceStream(PdfStream orig, PdfStream stream) throws IOException {
  orig.clear();
  orig.setData(stream.getBytes(false));
  for (PdfName name : stream.keySet()) {
    orig.put(name, stream.get(name));
  }
}
```

Now everything works fine, except:

- Bitone-images are not CCITT4, which they should be. (Doesn't matter, because they are converted to JBig2.)
- Images are said to have an error by Acrobat, but every other viewer displays just fine: There seems to be an error inside the ColorSpace information. That should be DeviceGray, but is CalGray with some Gamma-Information, but missing WhitePoint. Changing to DeviceGray by hand makes it work. A workaround is to strip gAMA and cHRM.

Both are conversion errors in iText7:

- CCITT4: PNGImageHelper line 254 should be `RawImageHelper.updateRawImageParameters(png.image, png.width, png.height, components, bpc, png.idat.toByteArray(), null);` to trigger conversion.
- WhitePoint is correctly read from the file and stored inside the ImageData-Class, but is discarded inside PdfImageXObject -> createPdfStream.